# plt.close('all') is not closing the image and hence the next statement is not getting excecuted

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plt.close('all') is not closing the image and hence the next statement is not getting excecuted

Tried to do plt.close('all')

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape)

plt.imshow(x_test[0])
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
print(tf.__version__)
```

Does not print tf.version until I close the image manually

Comment: The `plt.close('all')` will not be executed until you close the figure. 
Just put the `plt.show()` command at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the figure for 3 seconds and close it automatically.

```
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()
```

or another option is to put `plt.show()` at the end of the file.
The plt.close('all') will not be executed until you close the figure.